# Variable not being set when using a C# property in an MVC view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm sorry if its a newbie question but can anyone tell me why can't I set a value of a var to a c# property ?
i am trying to find a way to use the value to retrieve some model properties & do a calculation ....

```
@using System.Collections
@using System.Runtime.Serialization
@using CarRentalMVCApp.Models
@model CarRentalMVCApp.Models.Rentals


@functions {
    public string selection { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}



<script>

function select() {
    var $el = $("#selectedCar");
    var selected = $("#selectedCar option:selected").text();
    $el.on("change", @selection = selected);
    alert(@selection); 

}

function Rental() {

    var choice = select();
    @foreach (var car in ViewData["availableCars"] as IEnumerable<Vehicles>)
    {
        if (selection != null && int.Parse(selection) == car.מספר_רכב)
        {
            Price = car.עלות_ליום_השכרה;
        }
    }
    if (firstDay != null && lastDay != null) {
        var rentalData = {
            price: @Price,
            firstDay: $("#beginRental").val(),
            lastDay: $("#endRental").val()
        }
        alert(rentalData);
    }
}

</script>
```

the @selection always equals 0 and ones I try to set it with another veriable like so:

```
@selection = selected;
```

it remains 0 !!!

I also cant understand why I can't use any type of javascript variable if the @ sign is involved , would appresiate an explanation if you have the time or the links to help .....

Comment: Where are you setting the variable value ? Are you setting the value from a js variable ?

Comment: yes... trying to ...     $el.on("change", @selection = selected);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set a C# variable value in your client side code like the way you tried. Because when razor executes, it executes the C# code in it (***at server***) and the result of that (which could be string) will be send to the client to render the markup needed for the page.(Check the view source of the page).

So if you need to use this in your server code, you need to make an ajax call and send it to server

So if you want the price of the selected item value, make an ajax call  to your server and send the selected option value and using that calculate the price and return it.

```
var selected = $("#selectedCar option:selected").text();
$.get("@Url.Action("GetPrice","Home")"?id="+selected ,function(res){
    alert("Price of selection" + res);
});
```

Assuming `GetPrice` accepts a parameter with name `id` and  returns the price

```
public ActionResult GetPrice(int id)
{
  // based on this id, Get the corresponding price
  decimal price = 100.0M; //replace with your value from db
  return Json(price,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: do you happen to know how to send more than one parameter to the ActionResult with this type of syntax ?     I need to pull values of dates from an @HTML.editorfor chosen date but in the way you suggested it pulls blank values into the var ("") probably because the function you selected for pulling the value is .text() - the ActionResult I created is accepting DateTime values to do work and return an int ...

Comment: **because the function you selected for pulling the value is .text()**. No. I copied it from your question. Usually i use the value of the selected option using `val()` method. Without seeing how you are building the dropdown, i cannot tell you to use `val()` ! Hence i copied your existing code. Yes. You can send multipple items, If it is only one more value you want send, you may send it as another querystring item. If you have to send more data, change it to $.post and send whatever you want. There is no limitation when using $.post.

Comment: i am not building the dropdown , @HTML.editorfor is building it according to the model datatype ....  iv'e opened another question to get the code to show : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38944483/how-to-assign-variables-from-a-selected-html-editorfor-datetime-value-to-a-var

Answer (score 1):

MVC views are simply templates; there is not any sort of interoperation between C# and JavaScript. Rather, your C# variables simply cause text replacement. Therefore, these lines:

```
$el.on("change", @selection = selected);
alert(@selection);
```

...simply take the C# `selection` value and perform a substitution. So if `selection` is set to `"foo"` in the C#, the JavaScript that is output is:

```
$el.on("change", foo = selected);
alert(foo);
```

The event handler syntax for the `change` event is incorrect even if this did work. Plus, you cannot have JavaScript assign a value to a C# property. Rather, JavaScript will have to submit a form or perform an AJAX request to send data back to the server for processing, where it's handled by an MVC controller.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
The @ means that it's server code, not client code. It gets executed before the page is sent to the user. Once the server finishes and the user gets the page, javascript code get executed.